# How do I hide a Kendo Grid Column based on a value provided?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have the following Grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Something>()
.Name("GridName")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(m => m.Id).Hidden()
    columns.Bound(m => m.Name)
}))
```

I would like to hide ID depending on a value provided from the controller to the view.

How would I do this?

```
if (hideValue)
{
 .....
 ??
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the below code snippet.

**Method 1: (Using viewbag)**

View

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.TestModel

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Something>()
.Name("GridName")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(m => m.Id).Hidden(ViewBag.IsHideIDColumn);
    columns.Bound(m => m.Name);
}))
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    TestModel test = new TestModel();
    ViewBag.IsHideIDColumn = true;
    return View();
}
```

**Method 2: (Using strongly typed view)**

View

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.TestModel

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Something>()
.Name("GridName")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(m => m.Id).Hidden(Model.IsHideIDColumn);
    columns.Bound(m => m.Name);
}))
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    TestModel test = new TestModel();
    test.IsHideIDColumn = true;
    return View(test);
}
```

Model

```
public class TestModel
{
    public bool IsHideIDColumn { get; set; }
}
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: Can you do it on a per-item basis?  I tried .Hidden("#= FieldName#") to no avail.

Comment: @mike I think you need to use an ondatabound function to dynamically hide the columns - ex here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38137305/how-to-hide-or-show-the-columns-in-kendo-grid-conditionally

Comment: @Mike, did you ever figure this out?  I need the same thing.  I tried this ".Hidden("#= FieldName#") " also.

Comment: @RaniRadcliff - try the link I mentioned above - the OnDataBound was the only solution I found.